# Run .exe after taking PATH C++

Tags: c++, windows, exe

Can you help me? I need to run a file type of `.exe`. I have got two `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` files and in those files there are two *PATHes* to **pr1.exe** and **pr2.exe**. But in the first txt file I run **pr1.exe** and **pr2.exe** , in another one there are **pr2.exe** and **pr1.exe** .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cout << "argc = " << argc << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << "Argument: " << i << " = " << argv[i] << endl;
    }

    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    char ch;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(argv[1]);
    if (!infile) {
        cout << "errrrror: cant open a file" << argv[1];
        exit(-1);
    }
    while (infile) {
        infile.get(ch);
        cout << ch;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

For example: I write path of the `test1.txt` and it prints two PATHes of **pr1.exe** and **pr2.exe** it's like:

> "C:\Users\N\Desktop\process\The 2d file\Debug\The 2d file.exe"
>
> "C:\Users\N\Desktop\process\the 1st file\Debug\the 1st file.exe"

Can you advice me how I should run them?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `CreateProcess` function, more info can be found on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
    // start the program up
    #include "windows.h"

    std::wstring("pr1.exe");
    STARTUPINFO si;     
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    if(!CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR)wstr.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
           //error
    }

    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

Note: If you're not sending any command line paramaters with your program, you could also swap the first and second argument.

Comment: can you help me to build it?

Comment: Help you build it how? the code for it is in the question. I'll edit it to include `windows.h`, but that's really all you need